# React - API Call returning correct result but not passing along

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bing-api

I'm performing an API call to Bing Web Search API and running into an error with the response.

Here's the code:

```
await webSearchApiClient.web.search(searchText).then(result => {
    console.log('Results API', result)
    return result

}).catch((err) => {
    throw err;
})
```

The issue I'm running into is that the result does come back (the console log 'Results API' prints the expected return values), but the return statement isn't passing the value along. The rest of the code is written to be asynchronous, and when I print the values in the code calling the API function I get this:

```
Line 1: Results API {"_type": "SearchResponse","queryContext": {"originalQuery":...
Line 2: Returned Results undefined
```

I've tried setting the `result` to other variables with no success

I'm using redux as well, here's the code for the dispatch call and the code in the redux action (the second console log is the the redux actions):

```
const onSearchResults = async () => {   
    dispatch(getWebResults(searchText))
    dispatch(getImageResults(searchText))
}
```

```
export const getWebResults = (searchText) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const onStart = () => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_WEB_RESULTS_STARTED });
        }
        const onSuccess = (response) => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_WEB_RESULTS_SUCCESS, payload: response });
            return response;
        }
        const onError = (error) => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_WEB_RESULTS_FAILURE, payload: error });
            return error;
        }

        try {
            onStart();
            const webResults = await BingWebSearchApi(searchText);
            console.log('Returned Results', webResults)
            return onSuccess(webResults)
        } catch(error) {
            return onError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code that is printing `Returned Results undefined` so we can help debug that spot?

Comment: Just added some more for clarity

Comment: the first piece of code is `BingWebSearchApi` implementation right? It looks you should `return` your promise instead adding `await` at front of it.

Comment: Can you paste the entirety of `BingWebSearchApi` too? It looks like that is not returning the Promise you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
await webSearchApiClient.web.search(searchText).then(result => {
    console.log('Results API', result)
    return result

}).catch((err) => {
    throw err;
})
```

Since the return statement is for the then function scope, you should return the promise like this

```
return webSearchApiClient.web.search(searchText);
```

And then in your redux actions do something like

```
(...)

try {
  onStart();
  BingWebSearchApi(searchText).then((webResults)=> {
    console.log('Returned Results', webResults);
    onSuccess(webResults);
  });
} catch(error) {
  return onError(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, moving then to actions after the return statement fixed it